# What is the current going into a resistor-capacitor parallel circuit and the current coming out of it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I'm looking at the circuit below and know that I1 = I2. Can someone explain why those 2 currents are the same?

[image]

Comment: Not sure it is. If the capacitor is changing its charge it may not be.

Comment: @BillOnne It doesn't matter if the capacitor is changing its charge. Thats because a capacitor doesn't store charge. Charge is just moved from one plate to the other.

Comment: The two currents are the same because of conservation of charge. Kirchhoff's law of conservation of charge states that the total amount of current going into a junction must equal the total amount of current going out of the junction. In this case, the junction is the parallel combination of the resistor and capacitor.

Comment: One possible point of confusion is the role of the capacitor. Some think (erroneously) that a capacitor "stores" charge when it is "charged". It does not. When a capacitor is charged electrons are removed from one plate and deposited on the other plate making one plate more negative and the other more positive. But the total charge on the two plates remains unchanged.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply Kirchoff’s current law at the two nodes: $$i_1=i_R+i_C$$$$i_R+i_C=i_2$$ Then combine to get $$i_1=i_2$$

Answer (score 0):

[Kirchoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) applies to any isolated part of a circuit. So, draw a box around R and C, and insist that the total current into the box is zero.

Answer (score 0):

It might appear that because there is a charge storing device, the capacitor, the two current can be different and a difference in the currents results in the charge stored in the capacitor to change.
However the fact is that the net charge on the capacitor is **zero** in that a change in positive charge on one plate is always equal in magnitude to the change in negative charge on the other plate.
Since there is no net change in the charge stored in the capacitor the two currents must be equal which, of course, you would expect by applying Kirchhoff’s current law to the circuit.